# Unexpected result after data passes though _.each function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Each object in data.entries can have one of five values assigned as it's status value:

```
/*
Completed, Cancelled

Not Started, In Progress, Deffered
*/
```

After passing through the following block of code, the status of every entry returns as *open*, when they should be a mixture of *open* and *closed*, depending on the status when it enters the block.

```
_.each(data.entries, function(element){

    var entryStatus = _.chain(element)
      .countBy(function (i) { 

        if(i.status === 'Completed' || 'Cancelled'){
            i.status = 'closed';
        }

        if(i.status === 'Not Started' || 'In Progress' || 'Deffered'){
            i.status = 'open';
        }

        return i.status;

      })
      .value();

    element.entryStatus = entryStatus;

});
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here and why every status is returning as *open*?

Comment: I haven't used underscore.js but did you try `if(i.status === 'Completed' || i.status === 'Cancelled'){` ? Same with the other if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
if(i.status === 'Completed' || 'Cancelled'){
```

should be

```
if(i.status === 'Completed' || i.status === 'Cancelled'){
```

Same with the other `if` - you cant do multiple conditions like that. Most languages would fail to compile but javascript sees this as

```
if(i.status === 'Completed' || truthy_statement)
```

Which always evaluates `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not comparing correctly. Try:

```
if(i.status === 'Completed' || i.status === 'Cancelled'){
    i.status = 'closed';
}

if(i.status === 'Not Started' || i.status === 'In Progress' || i.status === 'Deffered'){
    i.status = 'open';
}
```

This will always result in being true:

```
if('In Progress' || 'Deffered'){
```